# How to have one dock widget on left edge of the screen and the other on the right edge

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget

I have been trying to get two `QDockWidget` to be not placed side by side, but instead, one on the left edge and the other on the right edge of the main window.

I have tried all the solutions from the Qt forums. Used `LeftDockWidgetArea` for left dock widget and `RightWidgetArea` for right. I have also called

```
setCorner(Qt::TopLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
setCorner(Qt::TopRightCorner, Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
setCorner(Qt::BottomLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
setCorner(Qt::BottomRightCorner, Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);

addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, leftDockWidget);
addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, rightDockWidget);
```

But the dock widgets are always placed side by side. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a picture demonstrating the problem.
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You might have confused StackOverflow with a forum. This is more of a Q/A site, with certain rules about [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: What platform is this on?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work both on Windows and Linux, as of Qt 5.

```
#include <QDockWidget>
...
QDockWidget* leftDockWidget = new QDockWidget(tr("Left Dock Widget"), this);
leftDockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
this->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea,leftDockWidget);
//
QDockWidget* rightDockWidget = new QDockWidget(tr("Right Dock Widget"), this);
rightDockWidget->setAllowedAreas(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
this->addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, rightDockWidget);
```